# Como criar tabela temporária espelhada em outra

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

É possível eu criar uma tabela temporária espelhada em outra?

*Exemplo:* Digamos que eu tenho em meu banco uma tabela com 60 campos. Gostaria de criar uma temp com o nome **#tabela** com a mesma estrutura da tabela no banco, mas sem precisar escrever os nomes dos campos e tipos, novamente. Isso é possível?

Comment: Já tentou criar uma view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplesmente:

```
SELECT * INTO #tabela
FROM TabelaOrigem
```

Answer (score 1):

View pode ser definida como uma tabela virtual composta por linhas e colunas de dados vindos de tabelas relacionadas em uma query (um agrupamento de SELECT’s, por exemplo).

```
CREATE VIEW active_users AS
SELECT id, username, ...
FROM users
WHERE active=True
```

Dessa forma você terá uma tabela virtual chamada active users

http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-criacao-da-view-views-no-sql-server-parte-1/22390

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Estou me familiarizando por aqui, alterei a resposta sendo mais objetiva com um exemplo. Acredito que agora poderá contribuir melhor para comunidade. Obrigado pelo conselho

Answer (score 1):

A ação de criar uma tabela temporária baseada em outra tabela no SQL Server pode ser feita durante um `select` qualquer. Poderá criar referenciando a tabela inteira ou apenas alguns campos.

Exemplo:

`SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM TABELA`

Você pode testar o resultado imediatamente verificando os registros na tabela temporária.

`SELECT * FROM #TEMP;`

Caso queira apenas uma amostra da tabela, poderá impor um limite no select do tipo `SELECT TOP 100` ou `SELECT TOP 1000` etc.

Lembrando que não será "copiado" nenhum `CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 1):

Para criar uma estrutura idêntica, mas sem qualquer conteúdo, pode utilizar a seguinte forma:

```
-- código #1
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#tabela','U') is not null DROP TABLE #tabela;

SELECT *
  into #tabela
  from minhatabela
  where 1 = 0;
```

Como a restrição da cláusula WHERE é falsa, somente a estrutura será copiada.

Comment: Diz, ao criar uma tabela sem dados, criei ela de forma temporária, mas não a encontro na árvore de tabelas. Ela existe, mas não vejo. Como eu faço?

Comment: @pnet: Tabelas temporárias ficam no banco de dados tempDB. As tabelas temporárias locais são visíveis apenas na sessão atual. Vide documentação em https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174979.aspx#Anchor_4